# Custom implementation of user status

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm trying to implement a custom security implementation which uses an extra field (enum which states the current status of the user, for example, PREREGISTRATION, ACTIVE, DISABLED, PASSWORD_CHANGED etc..)

```
public enum UserStatus {
    PRE_REGISTRATION,
    ACTIVE,
    DISABLED,
    PASSWORD_RESET_REQUESTED,
    PASSWORD_MUST_BE_RESETTED;
}
```

I would like to check the status of this user and throw a custom exception and send a different HttpStatus (not 403). I have added controls to `UserDetailsService` and added the following line:

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public UserDetailsServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository){
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException{
        ApplicationUser user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        if(user == null) throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
        if(user.getUserStatus()==UserStatus.PRE_REGISTRATION) throw new UserRegistrationNotCompleted(username);
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(),user.getPassword(),Collections.emptyList());
    }

}
```

However, I can not throw my own exception here as I have implemented `UserDetailsService` even though I extend `AuthenticationException` in my custom exception.

I don't want to use `UsernameNotFoundException` and send a customized message to the client. I would like to send a separate `HttpStatus` exception here.

Comment: What is you mean when say what u can't throw own exception? Which problem you have with this? U can throw any `RuntimeException` what you want.

Comment: Actually what i want is to send a new HttpStatus as a response to the request. I just tried to add a new AuthenticationException type and tried to catch it but it doesn't allow me to do so because im implementing an interface. Throwing a runtime is just a workaround, there must be a way to implement this in spring framework. Trying to find out how.